# "on Mondays" v. "on Monday" with the adverb, "always"

Tags: prepositions

Are all of these correct?

1. I wash my car on Mondays.
2. I always wash my car on Monday.
3. I always wash my car on Mondays.

I know #1 is correct, and it means every Monday. However, I'm not sure if #2 is correct. If we use the adverb "always," is it necessary to put the "s" at the end of "Monday"? I think for #3 the use of "always" adds emphasis to the fact that it is every Monday.

Answer (score 3):

While all three are correct, the use of both *always* and the plural *Mondays* in example 3 seems a bit redundant.  The first two would be more common and interchangeable.

SUPPLEMENT: As noted in the comments, there is a degree of ambiguity as to whether these sentences are inteded to mean that the car is washed *every* Monday, or only that, when it is washed, it would be on a Monday, but not necessarily every week.

To avoid ambiguity, you could say

> I wash my car every Monday.
>
> or
>
> Whenever I wash my car, it's on a Monday.

Comment: Am I reading too much into it if *I always wash my car on Monday* means *every Monday*, while *Mondays* means only on Monday, but not every Monday? I don't know, but to me there seems to be a difference.

Comment: @medica You have a good point. I think any of them could mean *only on Monday* but not necessarily *every Monday*.  But I think *every Monday* would be the more common takeaway. A bit of ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think any of them are explicit enough to definitely mean 'Every Monday I wash my car'. Am I missing something? To me, all three appear to suggest that I wash my car on Mondays but not necessarily every Monday. Somewhere the word 'every' needs to be applied to Monday, and the 'always' applied to car washing seems irrelevant.